# maven-resource-plugin overwrite=true ignored - newer file is kept

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I want to overwrite the log4j2.xml in src/main/resources
for this i put 3 files in config/PROD, config/DEV, config/QA

and added this copy-resources element:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <!-- in validate phase copy the folder in config folder with name given by variable into classes-->
            
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>copy-resources</id>
                  <phase>validate</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>          
                      <resource>
                        <directory>config/${target.environment}</directory>
                      </resource>
                    </resources>              
                  </configuration>          
                </execution>
              </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But this only works if log4j2.xml has an older "Changed" date than the files on config.
Even adding the overwrite in global config instead of per execution it does not help.

Only changing the changed timestamp of files is helping. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `copy-resources` goal of `maven-resources-plugin` should be used to copy resources to a **generic** output folder (for example a "distribution" folder), not to the `target` folder that is the default destination of the default goal.

If you have a default resource directory and a per-environment directory, just specify them in the `<build><resources>` section as explained in https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

For example:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>config/${target.environment}</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    ....

</build>
```

In your POM you have bound `copy-resources` to the `validate` phase that [takes precedence](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.4/maven-core/lifecycles.html) over the `process-resources` phase used by default, so your `<overwrite>` switch has no effect because the copy from `config/${target.environment}` happens always before the copy from `src/main/resources`.

If your `log4j2.xml` is already present in `config/DEV`, `config/QA` and `config/PROD`, you should simply remove it from `src/main/resources`;  if you want to keep it for any other environment you have to override the default configuration of the plugin (inherited from the Super POM) in this way:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-resources</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Note also that `${basedir}` has been deprecated in favor of `${project.basedir}`, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.4/maven-model-builder/#model-interpolation

Comment: does this mean overwrite is ignored by intention?
this i tried first but how to set overwrite here? i want to overwrite log4j2.xml that from src/main/resources (if present in config/${target.environment})

Comment: I have just answered by editing my post above.

Comment: thanks - you pointed in right direction. but i want that the default (resources/log4j2.xml) is always overwritten if one is present in config folder. what i did now: mention the default-resources execution before mine (this makes it execute before mine if on same phase) and mine bound also to process-resources with overwrite true.

Comment: My answer satisfies your requirement: remove the `copy-resources` execution and keep my two blocks of code. I think that my solution is more "standard" than using `copy-resources` because It uses just one execution (the standard one with `overwrite=true`)  instead of two.

Comment: undertood now - your are right, thx again